# How to properly resize canvas according to screen size? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, coordinates, mouse, screen-management, position

So, as the question says I need to resize the canvas according to screen size. However the thing is that that's not it. I also need to have the mouse coordinates updated proportionally. Seems like I made a fatal mistake of not considering screen sizes from the start since this is my first proper game. I made the game on basis of my 1080p screen. Things like positioning stuff and checking mouse coordinates are all based on a 1920x1080 canvas. Please help!

Github links:

1. Main game, will work but size will depend on your screen: https://proqbr.github.io/powerdown/
2. all the files(only 15MB in case you'd like to see by downloading): https://github.com/proqbr/powerdown
3. sketch.js (pretty much main file regarding this): https://github.com/proqbr/powerdown/blob/master/sketch.js

Main thing is in sketch.js, On **lines 260-263** are some createCanvas lines in `function setup()`, the uncommented one is `createCanvas(1920,1080);` as it's what i was working with. And on **lines 302-314** are a bunch of camera.zoom lines, uncommented one is `camera.zoom = 1;` since on my screen there was no required zoom for the main menu.

Line 352 onwards is some code on knowing where the player clicked, the problem is this. I do know how to make the canvas's contents look properly resized on all screens by using `windowWidth` & `windowHeight` however it's the incorrect mouse coordinates which causes the problem. It would be great if someone could help.

In case there's some problem with the game on your side, here's a quick second video how the game menu works, although it's pretty straightforward anyways: https://youtu.be/eZZw5CmOXEE

Comment: Assume a reader won't click external links, and edit your question so that it includes a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the code needed to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @DMGregory Ah actually the code is kinda big so even if i added the main code it would get a little long. that's why i left a link to the main file separately(sketch.js)

Comment: Then it sounds like you haven't yet created a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, which is one of the steps we recommend to help you get good answers fast